# How to group into batches after assigning rank

Tags: sql, presto, ranking, dense-rank, ranking-functions

I have a table that I'm first trying to group based on unique column values (using `dense_rank`) and then further group those items into batches of 5. Below is my table:

| video_id | frame_id | verb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| video_a | frame_1 | walk |
| video_a | frame_2 | run |
| video_a | frame_3 | sit |
| video_a | frame_4 | walk |
| video_a | frame_5 | walk |
| video_a | frame_6 | walk |
| video_b | frame_7 | stand |
| video_b | frame_8 | stand |
| video_b | frame_9 | run |
| video_b | frame_10 | run |
| video_b | frame_11 | sit |
| video_b | frame_12 | run |
| video_b | frame_13 | run |

And below is what I'm trying to get:

| video_id | frame_id | verb | batch_of_five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| video_a | frame_1 | walk | 1 |
| video_a | frame_2 | run | 1 |
| video_a | frame_3 | sit | 1 |
| video_a | frame_4 | walk | 1 |
| video_a | frame_5 | walk | 1 |
| video_a | frame_6 | walk | 2 |
| video_b | frame_7 | stand | 3 |
| video_b | frame_8 | stand | 3 |
| video_b | frame_9 | run | 3 |
| video_b | frame_10 | run | 3 |
| video_b | frame_11 | sit | 3 |
| video_b | frame_12 | run | 4 |
| video_b | frame_13 | run | 4 |

Where each `video_id` has a unique rank and each batch of 10 within each ranked `video_id` has its own unique rank (and each batch of 10 overall has a unique id regardless of whether they belong to the same `video_id` or not).

I'm able to group based on the `video_id` column but am having trouble grouping those items further so that they are both in batches of 10 and unique across all `video_ids`. I thought about using a group by clause but I'm trying to keep the other columns intact as well (`verb` column).

Here is my presto query so far:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        -- Give each unique video_id a unique rank
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY video_id) AS video_batch
    FROM videos
)
```

Comment: Why does batch 2 only have one row?

Comment: The `video_a` id has 6 rows which I wanted to divide into batches of 5, but I don't want the batches of 5 to spill over across videos. So the first 5 rows of `video_a` belong to batch 1 and the leftover row 6 belongs to batch 2. Then the rows in `video_b` belong to their own batches of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate frame rank (partition by video_id), divide by 6 (integer division) to get batch number in video_id partition. Then rank again to get absolute batch number:

```
with sample_data as(        
select 'video_a' as video_id, 'frame_1' as frame_id , 'walk' as verb union all 
select 'video_a', 'frame_2' , 'run'   union all
select 'video_a', 'frame_3' , 'sit'   union all
select 'video_a', 'frame_4' , 'walk'  union all
select 'video_a', 'frame_5' , 'walk'  union all
select 'video_a', 'frame_6' , 'walk'  union all
select 'video_b', 'frame_7' , 'stand' union all
select 'video_b', 'frame_8' , 'stand' union all
select 'video_b', 'frame_9' , 'run'   union all
select 'video_b', 'frame_10', 'run'   union all
select 'video_b', 'frame_11', 'sit'   union all
select 'video_b', 'frame_12', 'run'   union all
select 'video_b', 'frame_13', 'run'
)

select s.*, 
       dense_rank() over(order by video_id, rnk_frame / 6) batch_of_five
from
(
select video_id, frame_id, verb, 
       CAST(regexp_extract(frame_id,'_(\d*)$',1) AS INT) frame_number,
       dense_rank() over(partition by video_id order by CAST(regexp_extract(frame_id,'_(\d*)$',1) AS INT)) rnk_frame
  from sample_data
)s
order by video_id, frame_number;
```

Result:

```
video_id    frame_id    verb    frame_number    rnk_frame   batch_of_five
video_a     frame_1     walk    1                1           1
video_a     frame_2     run     2                2           1
video_a     frame_3     sit     3                3           1
video_a     frame_4     walk    4                4           1
video_a     frame_5     walk    5                5           1
video_a     frame_6     walk    6                6           2
video_b     frame_7     stand   7                1           3
video_b     frame_8     stand   8                2           3
video_b     frame_9     run     9                3           3
video_b     frame_10    run     10               4           3
video_b     frame_11    sit     11               5           3
video_b     frame_12    run     12               6           4
video_b     frame_13    run     13               7           4
```

I extracted frame_number to sort as integer, not as string, to get the same sort order as in your question (some sorting column is absolutely necessary), if you already have rank as you mentioned in question, you can use it instead.